# Are static variables strongly held by default?

Tags: objective-c, static

If I have the following method:

```
+ (instancetype) instance {
    static MySingleton *instance;
    if (!instance) {
        instance = [MySingleton new];
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Am I guaranteed to get the same exact `instance` every time? Is there any way `instance` might be deallocated by ARC?

Comment: static variables are strong by default. You should use the pattern with dispatch_once to create singletons to be threadsafe. And use [[MySingleton alloc] init]. And test for nil pointers by comparing with nil.

Comment: @gnasher729 I understand the `dispatch_once` thing, but why the second two?